# pageContext.request.contextPath not working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, contextpath

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.32 and I'm trying to include a JSP file into another, but somehow the file cannot be found (yes, the file exists). Here is the file structure and code:

```
<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/templates/header.jsp">
</jsp:include>

WebContent
- folder/caller.jsp
- templates/header.jsp
```

However, if I use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} outside of that to check if it outputs correctly, it works, does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not even sure if you can use runtime variables inside a `<jsp:include>`, but the other problem is that [the `contextPath` refers](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) to the context of the URL being requested from the server, and does not necessarily correspond to your filesystem layout.

Why wouldn't you just use `<jsp:include page="templates/header.jsp">`?

Comment: You can use EL in `jsp:include` attributes (but not in `@include`). But the problem is indeed that he somehow assumes/thinks that `jsp:include` runs in the webbrowser by URL instead of in the webserver by relative webcontent path.

Comment: @BalusC, @matt yes, I realize that now, it was easily fixed just by using `<jsp:include page="/templates/header.jsp">` I'm a newcomer to JSP, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

i completely agree with the above answer however if u have to use it this way then the below code shd work

```
<c:set var="myContext" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<jsp:include page="${myContext}/templates/header.jsp"> </jsp:include>
```