# contextPath is empty in JSP page while using it with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, servlets

I want to load CSS on the JSP page. But I am getting empty pageContext.request.contextPath in JSP page. I am using this approach because if I move the page around in different directories within the templates or JSP then I should not need to keep on making changes to paths of referred CSS or js files.

Jsp page is as below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "x" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/default-theme.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <H2>Reached Home.</H2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties file is as below

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I am using Spring version 2.6.0. Along with the following dependencies in pom.xml-
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-tomcat (scope: provided)
tomcat-embed-jasper (scope: provided)
jstl

As per Spring Boot, pageContext is Implicit. Then what could be going wrong here?
Any help or suggestions would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

check if remove <%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
if not work test : request.getContextPath()

after all see this link :
[pageContext.request.contextPath not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877354/pagecontext-request-contextpath-not-working)